# jquery parse XML that is in a td returned from server

Tags: jquery, xml

Making an ajax call to return some data from the server. The data comes back as such:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Field Name</td>
        <td>Field Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SuccessFlag</td>
        <td>True</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ResponseMessage</td>
        <td><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
            <License>
                <CustomerID>Bob</CustomerID>
                <License>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX</License>
                <Log>Created by lt@email.com on December 6, 2012, 1:09 pm Cancelled by b@email.com on December 6, 2012, 1:09 pm</Log>
                <ExpirationDate>2012-12-06</ExpirationDate>
            </License>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am able to output the data like this:

```
//ajax call stuff
success: function(data) {
    var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();
    var message = $(data).find("td:eq(5)").text();
if (answer==="True") {
        $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').val("");
        $('#resultGenerate').show().html('<ul><li>' + message + '</li></ul>');
    } else {
        $('.processing').hide();
        $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').val("");
        $('#resultGenerate').show().html('<ul><li>' + answer + '</li><li>' + message +    
        '</ul>');
    }
}
```

basically I just go to the 5th td of the table and output the message. I need to format back into a table or more well constructed output. I am assuming I would create a function to parse out each tag and value pair and then run the function? Need some assistance, thank you as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your text just call parseXML to have jQuery turn it into an object you can work with:

```
var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();
var message = $(data).find("td:eq(5)").html();
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( message );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
// Now loop through the markup
$xml.each(function(){
    // Do something with the license
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the time! So I'm not putting the above in the right place, where in my ajax call would this go?

Comment: I have added your code to my post so you can see the context. This suggestion puts your XML parsing right after getting the message text. I'm not sure where or how you want to use the message data later in your code, but this should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure that getting just the text with .text() is the problem because that strips all the markup out. I edited the example above to use .html() to get the message data. Can you try that and see what happens?

Comment: This line is the error(Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier): if (answer==="True") {

Comment: My code example is wrong. I was missing a closing ); after the each function.

Comment: still no dice, I had already added the closing ); now it returns "Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method 'parseXML' " could it be a scope issue?

Comment: weird as that is strait from jquery documentation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20714/discussion-between-davidethell-and-dirty-bird-design)